# sheet on the right side of the screen in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to the development of andorid how could I do a modal that comes out of the right part of the screen,

as the image I publish[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR6RQ.png)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout) for this. It is mostly used for navigation purposes but I don't think there is anything stops you from using your own custom content in it.

Comment: thank you very much I think it's a good way to apply it I will implement it